# in batch, how do I allow two options and nothign else?

Tags: batch-file

ok so what I've tried to do is allow two specific options - a and b, and allow nothing else
for example

```
if %test% == A goto test
if %test% == B goto test1
```

and I want to make it so that anything other than A or B sends it to an error option - something like this

```
echo That is not a valid option!
```

but I've had a pretty hard time figuring it out. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just add an unconditional `goto option_error` after your 2 lines!

Comment: See `choice /?`. You are using wrong commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %test% == A goto test
if %test% == B goto test1
echo That is not a valid option!
```

is probably the simplest, given what you've shown us.

Comment: Jesus christ I'm a fool. Thanks

Comment: @threehundred, I would not say you are a fool, you simply seemed to confuse [tag:batch-file] with a true programming language; batch files are basically executed line by line from top to bottom, unless you explicitly change that direction by commands like `goto`, `call` and `if`, `for`; in your case, since none of the `if` conditions are met, the line after the `if` queries is executed; by the way, I recommend to use quotes like `if "%test%"=="A"` in order to avoid trouble in case `%test%` is empty...

Comment: @threehundred if the answer by Magoo helped you, consider accepting it as answer by clicking the checkmark symbol under the voting buttons :)

Comment: @aschipfl, programming BASIC, FORTRAN and PASCAL back in the 80's wasn't much different.

Comment: True, @Squashman, I somehow erased them from my memories... ;-) I guess I should have said "modern programming languages"...